# How do I find and updated MPC header file to avoid "warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3."

Tags: mingw, version, gfortran, mpc

I am using MINGW on windows. I am compiling a old program using gfortran function. I have been received the following error:

`warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.`

I have ran the MINGW installation manager and have confirmed that I have 1.0.3 version of MPC library. The only mpc.h file I could find has the 1.0.3 version number in it so I am unsure of what header file it is finding/using.

The output log as generated by CodeBlocks is as follows (with unrelated warnings removed):

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in GENMAT (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "GENMAT - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in GENMAT (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -static -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument  -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals     -c C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\adip.f -o obj\Debug\adip.o
gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -static -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument  -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals     -c C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\blayer.f -o obj\Debug\blayer.o
gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -static -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument  -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals     -c C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\begin.f -o obj\Debug\begin.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\adip.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/f951.exe C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\adip.f -ffixed-form -quiet -dumpbase adip.f -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip obj\Debug\adip.o -g -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wcompare-reals -std=legacy -std=legacy -version -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -J obj\Debug\ -fintrinsic-modules-path c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/finclude -o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\ccY7H4lQ.s
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\blayer.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/f951.exe C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\blayer.f -ffixed-form -quiet -dumpbase blayer.f -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip obj\Debug\blayer.o -g -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wcompare-reals -std=legacy -std=legacy -version -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -J obj\Debug\ -fintrinsic-modules-path c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/finclude -o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\cceA5LfP.s
GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU Fortran2008 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\blayer.f:902:9:
GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU Fortran2008 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\adip.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -v -o obj\Debug\adip.o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\ccY7H4lQ.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\adip.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\blayer.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -v -o obj\Debug\blayer.o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\cceA5LfP.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\blayer.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -static -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument  -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -g -v -std=legacy -fbacktrace -Wcompare-reals     -c C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\t35a9.f -o obj\Debug\t35a9.o
gfortran.exe -LC:\MinGW\include -o bin\Debug\GENMAT.exe obj\Debug\adip.o obj\Debug\blayer.o obj\Debug\begin.o obj\Debug\t35a9.o   
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\begin.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/f951.exe C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\begin.f -ffixed-form -quiet -dumpbase begin.f -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip obj\Debug\begin.o -g -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wcompare-reals -std=legacy -std=legacy -version -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -J obj\Debug\ -fintrinsic-modules-path c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/finclude -o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5SR2KI.s
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU Fortran2008 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\t35a9.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/f951.exe C:\Users\michaelb\Documents\Pioneer\Coding\Workspaces\GENMAT\t35a9.f -ffixed-form -quiet -dumpbase t35a9.f -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip obj\Debug\t35a9.o -g -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wcompare-reals -std=legacy -std=legacy -version -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fcheck=bounds -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -J obj\Debug\ -fintrinsic-modules-path c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/finclude -o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5YVJ7I.s
GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU Fortran2008 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\t35a9.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -v -o obj\Debug\t35a9.o C:\Users\michaelb\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5YVJ7I.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-J' 'obj\Debug\' '-Wall' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-static' '-Wno-unused-variable' '-Wno-unused-dummy-argument' '-fcheck=bounds' '-fcheck=all' '-g' '-v' '-std=legacy' '-fbacktrace' '-Wcompare-reals' '-c' '-o' 'obj\Debug\t35a9.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
Output file is bin\Debug\GENMAT.exe with size 4.87 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 14 second(s))
0 error(s), 220 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 14 second(s))
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What exact command are you running?

Comment: The `-I` compiler flag can tell the compiler to load `mpc.h` from a different location. How do you know for sure the `mpc.h` you checked is actually the one used by your build process?

Comment: I added the build logs which contain the build commands to the main post. And I suspect that the mpc.h file that I checked is incorrect as it is still producing the error. Is there a way to determine which headers your code is incorporating?

Comment: Note that what you received is a warning, not an error. It is still quite peculiar but the API is unlikely to change between minor versions. I would start by running `find` and locating all `mpc.h` files in your computer.

Comment: Actually, isn't gfortran actually complaining that the library it sees is 1.0.3 while it was compiled for 1.0.2? Unlikely to matter.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I do realize that this was a warning and not an error. I was just trying to solve and understand it. Thanks Vladimir for that explanation. I will just ignore the warning then.